# Cannot connect on PostgreSQL From remote

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, remote-access, firewall

I installed postgresql on my ubuntu 23.04 hosted on OVH, and I want to configure it to be accessible from remote.

This is my postgresql.conf
[image: postgresql.conf]

And this is my pg_hba.conf
[image: pg_hba.conf]

And here are all of the ports allowed (I used ufw status)[image: ufw status]

When I try to connect with pgAdmin I received Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired.

When I use telnet to reach to the 5432 too, I received this error : Unable to open a connection to the host, on port 5432: Connection failed

I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: 1) This is a dangerous setup allowing access from anywhere. You are asking for the Postgres instance to be hacked. 2) To your question add details of what  happens when you try to connect. 3) Describe where the Postgres instance is, on your computer, in the cloud or elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but I think md5 protect it with a password or Am I wrong?

I added more details to the error I encoutered I don't if it help?

Comment: 1) All it takes is a weak password or someone changing `pg_hba.conf` to a permissive mode and your database is hacked/broken. The best way to protect the database is to not allow direct connection from the internet. 2) The error messages indicate there is probably another firewall between the client and the database. This is probably due to the questions I asked in number 3 in my previous comment, which you have not answered.

Comment: thanks a lot I will check i and add more security, I mentionned it on the post that my postgres instance is installed on OVH. I checked on OVH but there is no firewall enabled in my case edge firewall is disabled

Comment: SSH into the remote instance and verify that the Postgres instance is up and running `ps ax | grep postgres`  and that it is listening on 5432 `sudo netstat -tunlp`. If so then either 1) You did not restart the server after making the conf file changes.  2) There is something(firewall) blocking the remote connection.

Comment: I checked it and postgres is running and it is listening on 5432. So there is other think which block the remote connection

Comment: What address on the server is Postgres listening on? Could it be the connection you are attempting a connection on is using an address that the server is not listening on? Could be that the address is private to the OVH network and not publicly reachable.

Comment: I think postgresql listen to all adresses, I configure the postgresql.conf to listen_adresses="*".

Comment: `listen_adresses="*"` means the server will listen on all available IP interfaces on the 'machine'. The issue is on the client end, whether the connection string is using an address that is reachable from outside the cloud hosting. Often cloud instances have two exposed addresses/host names a private one for within the hosting cloud and one that is exposed to the public internet. These are then mapped to the IP interface on the `machine`. If you are using the private address in the remote client connection string you will not make a connection, you need to use the public address.

Comment: I did not understand well your question, for OVH they just give one adress to connect and I use it to connect to the server. I tried to enable another port to check it and it's not work

Comment: 1) This *...OVH they just give one adress to connect and I use it to connect to the server.* does not make sense. If you can connect to server why do you say you can't? 2) I think this is something you need to discuss with OVH tech support.